# No such element exception. Unable to locate element in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, data-mining, data-extraction

I want to scrape email from  https://www.archionweb.be/ on this page https://www.archionweb.be/Public/Company/1930.

Email is protected in the captcha, So idea is to click on the captcha then extract the email. But Whenever I tried to click on the captcha button (I have used both XPath and CSS selector) there is exception:

> "no such element: Unable to locate element"

Please If anyone can help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we are Automating even after clicking on `I am not a Robot` it sometimes gave another re-captcha. Was able to click on the checkbox with below code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="path to chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get("https://www.archionweb.be/Public/Company/1930")
time.sleep(5)
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@title='reCAPTCHA']")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
time.sleep(5)
recaptcha = driver.find_element_by_class_name("recaptcha-checkbox-borderAnimation")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",recaptcha)
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(recaptcha).click().perform()
time.sleep(2)
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```